# How to show Error message from FBgraph API

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `FBgraph API` and now I want to print Error message in a single line like

> (#341) Feed action request limit reached

Below are the response from FBgraph API:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x6b273c0 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x6b26560 [0x1c91b48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x6b26380 [0x1c91b48]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6b26990 [0x1c91b48]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x6b26930 [0x1c91b48]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x6b268d0 [0x1c91b48]>{contents = "(#341) Feed action request limit reached"}
    6 : <CFString 0x6b271d0 [0x1c91b48]>{contents = "code"} = 341
}
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the request carries 3 different types of error message you can read.
Error
[Error localizedDescription]
[Error description]

One of these might give you the line you want.

Oh, there's also [error userinfo]